# Sub vector space for polynomial vectors

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I was asked to check whether the following set W = {P(x) $\in$ Cn[x] | P(1) = P(2)}
Is a sub vector space of Cn[x].

I know that P(1)=0 is indeed a sub vector space because P(1)=0 is
1. Not an empty set (x-1)
2. Closed under the operation of addition (P(1)+Q(1)=0+0=0)
3. Closed under the operation of multiplication of a scalar (a*P(1) = a*0 = 0)

But in my case I don't know how to start, should I start with
P(1)-P(2)=0?
P(1)-P(2)+Q(1)-Q(2)=0+0=0?
a(P(1)-P(2)) = a*0=0?

Thank you

Comment: Yes: what you are proposing is exactly wht you have to do.

Comment: In that case W is a subspace, right?

Comment: Yes: $W$ is a subspace.